# Adding another input field when a add button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im trying to create an app that will have fields a user can enter information into.  The problem is I don't know how many fields that will be.  For example, lets say you have a recipe app where you enter the ingredients in.  Some recipes may have 2 ingredients and some may have more.  What I am wanting is the option if there are more fields needed than what is on the screen presently, the user can press a add button and it will create the additional fields as needed instead of having some potentially unused fields. I've been looking around trying to find an example of what I'm looking for and not having any luck.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try using a `UITableView` with custom cells containing `UITextField` on it. So on `Add` button click just add another cell.

Answer (score 0):

best approach will be a UITableView. There you can add as much cell as you need.

[There is a apples example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html) though it not as like as you want but you can get the picture.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 Try this it will help you..
```

```
<pre><div id="divingredient" class="input_wrapar_search">
    <span>Ivingredient Type : </span>
    <input type="text"  maxlength="50"  id="txtIngredient0" />
</div> </pre>
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    $("[id$=btnaddnew]").live("click", function (e) {
        counter++;
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Can not add more than 10 price !");
            return false;
        }
        $("#divingredient").append('<input type="text"  maxlength="50"  id="txtIngredient' + counter + '" />');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
    $("[id$=btnremove]").live("click", function (e) {

        if (counter == 0) {
            alert("one price is manadatory !");
            return false;
        }
        $("#txtIngredient" + counter).remove();
        counter--;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnaddnew" runat="server" Class="btn" Text="Add New" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnremove" runat="server" Class="btn" Text="Remove" /></pre>
```

Comment: This is not a asp .net problem its an iOS related problem. Please read before you answer any question.